No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Omit<T, keyof T>'
I need to exclude or pick some fields from an object just like how Pick and Omit works with types.
I implemented pick function like below but I have a hard time implementing an exclude function.
The ts compiler throws the error No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Omit<T, keyof T>'.
I also tried to search for a solution online but each time I see the result for the Omit type.
Here is the pick function which works perfectly, a better approach is welcome:
export function pick<T extends Object>(
  obj: T,
  ...s: [keyof T]
): Pick<T, keyof T> {
  const returnValue = {} as Pick<T, keyof T>;
  s.forEach((k) => {
    returnValue[k] = obj[k];
  });
  return returnValue;
}

And here an exclude function where I got compile errors on line returnValue[e[0]] = obj[e[0]]  .
I expected it to work fine but seems like I don't understand something.
What am I missing here?
export function exclude<T extends Object>(
  obj: T,
  ...s: [keyof T]
): Omit<T, keyof T> {
  const returnValue = {} as Omit<T, keyof T>;
  Object.entries(obj).forEach((e) => {
    if (!s.includes(e[0] as keyof T))
      returnValue[e[0]] = obj[e[0]]
  });

  return returnValue;
}

I tried looking online for casting string to keyof object but couldn't find anything.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have two unrelated problems and SO questions should have just one problem. • Omit<T, keyof T> is going to be {}. Why are you writing that? Maybe Partial<T> is what you're looking for? • You'd have to write e[0] as keyof T every time, unless you copy it to a new variable like const e0 = e[0] as keyof T and use e0 from then on. • Both are shown in this playground link. Please [edit] to fix one of those issues and we'll answer the other (or find a suitable duplication target), unless I'm missing something about the question.

After trying multiple solution and the code below was exactly what I am looking for. Even though it allows duplicate parameter when calling the function, it still achieves the same result. I hope this will help others who look for the solution.
export function pick<T, S extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...s: S[]): Pick<T, S> {
  const returnValue = {} as Pick<T, S>;

  s.forEach((k) => {
    returnValue[k] = obj[k];
  });

  return returnValue;
}

export function exclude<T extends Object, S extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  ...s: S[]
): Omit<T, S> {
  const returnValue = {} as Omit<T, S>;
  Object.entries(obj).forEach((e) => {
    if (!s.includes(e[0] as S))
      returnValue[e[0] as keyof Omit<T, S>] = obj[
        e[0] as keyof Omit<T, S>
      ] as any;
  });

  return returnValue;
}

